# Is custom condition supported in the AWS cloud front policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In AWS cloud front, for private content delivery there are two options:

1. Signed URL
2. Signed Cookies

In custom policy inside the statement they have defined:

```
    {
"Statement": [
      {
         "Resource":"URL or stream name of the object",
         "Condition":{
            "DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":required ending date and time in Unix time format and UTC},
            "DateGreaterThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":optional beginning date and time in Unix time format and UTC},
            "IpAddress":{"AWS:SourceIp":"optional IP address"}
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In the condition they talk about only 3 types of condition settings.

My question is - Are custom policy possible here? Say pass a string token and validate if that token is?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  With a custom policy, anything in the query string (other than what's used for a signed URL) is part of the `Resource`, and must be present if specified.  But the policy is not a secret document, so making a URL match the policy is as simple as decoding the policy from base64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is - Are custom policy possible here? Say pass a string
>   token and validate if that token is?

**This is not currently possible**. According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-examples) only the following fields are allowed inside the policy (Since this is not an IAM policy)

- Rosource
- DateLessThan
- DateGreaterThan (Optional)
- IpAddress (Optional)